# Prevent Sublime Text 4 from opening previous files ONLY when launching via file

Tags: sublimetext4

I'm on Sublime Text Build 4143. The way I want my workflow is:

- If opening the application directly via Applications, then restore previously open files
- If opening via file from Finder, only open that one file and do not restore previously open files

I know I can completely disable or enable session restore on application boot, but I would rather it be conditional based on whether or not I'm already opening a file.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think this is possible. Enabling/disabling session restore is a global setting, and even if it wasn't, I don't think there's a way to change it based on how the application is opened.